# Alternative expression to the Moyal star-product

Tags: lie-groups, dynamical-systems, quantum-mechanics, deformation-theory

Is there an alternative version of the Moyal star-product where:
$$f(q,p)\star g(q,p)=f(D_q,D_p)g(q,p)$$
where $D_q,D_p$ are just some differential operators? I recall having seen something like that but I cannot find a reference anymore.

Comment: This is normally called "the [Bopp shift](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578522/why-does-the-star-product-satisfy-the-bopp-shift-relations-fx-p-star-gx-p)" after an early user.